# Install extensions in PG admin

Tags: postgresql, installation

I tried to install the extensions for postgressql. i opened the query toool in pgadmin 4.

```
enter code here CREATE EXTENSION postgis;`enter code here`
```

Unfortunetly i didnt work with the error :
ERROR:  Konnte Erweiterungskontrolldatei »C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/16/share/extension/postgis.control« nicht öffnen: No such file or directory.Erweiterung »postgis« ist nicht verfügbar

FEHLER:  Erweiterung »postgis« ist nicht verfügbar
SQL state: 0A000
Detail: Konnte Erweiterungskontrolldatei »C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/16/share/extension/postgis.control« nicht öffnen: No such file or directory.
Hint: Die Erweiterung muss zuerst auf dem System, auf dem PostgreSQL läuft, installiert werden.

Comment: Is the PostGIS code available on your PC ?